# Should I check the status when doing HTTP POST or PUT requests with XHR?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

This is a weird question I got after watching some videos about XHR and Async JS from an Udemy Course. There was a section where we create a simple library for making HTTP Requests in ES5. It started like this:

```
function EasyHTTP() {
  this.http = new XMLHttpRequest;
}

// Make an HTTP GET Request
EasyHTTP.prototype.get = function(url, callback) {
  this.http.open('GET', url, true);

  let self = this;
  this.http.onload = function() {
    if (self.http.status === 200) {
      callback(null, self.http.responseText)
    } else {
      callback('Error: ' + self.http.status)
    }
  }

  this.http.send();
}
```

I understood everything. But when the instructor was writing the `post` method, he did almost the same as in `get` method but said "We don't need to check the status, because we're doing a POST request" and the final method for POST ended up like this:

```
// Make an HTTP POST Request
EasyHTTP.prototype.post = function(url, data, callback) {
  this.http.open('POST', url, true);
  this.http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

  let self = this;
  this.http.onload = function() {
    callback(null, self.http.responseText)
  }

  this.http.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

And he did the same for the `put` method. But for the `delete` he checked the status like in the `get` method.  I am confused, should we really "ignore" the status when doing POST and PUT requests? Why?

Comment: "*We don't need to check the status, because we're doing a POST request*" - that's absolute rubbish. POST and PUT requests have responses with status codes as well. Your hunch is correct. Not handling errors from network resources is negligient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should we really "ignore" the status when doing POST and PUT requests?

No, you should check for status code.

All HTTP request methods, including POST and PUT, return a response indicating a failure or success, you should check the status and show to the user that their request was successful or it failed.